# how to add delay to the cell click event in grid panel

Tags: extjs

this is throwing an error saying h is null or not an object in ext-all.debug.js
at function createDelayed(h, o, scope){
    return function(){
        var args = TOARRAY(arguments);
        (function(){
            h.apply(scope, args);
        }).defer(o.delay || 10);
    };
};

here is the code i used

grid.on('click', this.onClick, this, {
                single: true,
                delay: 10000,
                forumId: 4
            });

Answer (score 0):

Probably means `this.onClick` is not a valid function reference.  Hard to tell from what you've posted.  Does it work correctly without the extra options argument?